# Modular congruence rules

Tags: congruences

May take exponent of both sides of a modular congruence? 
For instance, may I write

> $$n^2\equiv-1\mod p \quad \rm as \quad(n^2)^{2k+1}\equiv (-1)^{2k+1}\mod p ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p|(a-b)$ does $p|a^k-b^k$?

Comment: p|a^k-b^k as a^k-b^k can be written as (a-b)times something?

Comment: If the answer to my question is yes, can you conclude that the result is true? Remember what it means for $a\cong b \mod p$. It means that $p|a-b$.

Comment: The result is true.

Comment: Yup, it is true. There are more than one way to show it. The way I told you is one of them.

Comment: Since I can always factor (n^2)^2k+1-(-1)^2k+1,right?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if $a\equiv b \mod n$ then for every polynomial $f\in {\mathbb{Z}}[x]$ you have
$f(a)\equiv f(b) \mod  n .$